# Adding a Button dynamically in a Table using HTML and Java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image][Hi I have Table, I have to add a Button, beside the +, when ever I click on it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkQlu.png)

The code is not working. I do not understand why.

```js
function addProject() {
        var r = $('<input/>').attr({
            type: "button",
            id: "field",
            value: 'Project'
        });
       $("#idProject").parent().append(r);
    }
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
    
    <tr>

        <td style="text-align:center; width:8%"></td>
          <td style="text-align:center; width:8%"><input id="idProject" type="button" style="border:1px solid grey;text-align:center;background-color:#E0EEEE" value="+" onclick=addProject() /></td>
    </tr>
    
</tbody>
 </table>
  </html>
```

Comment: You are using **JQuery** too right?

Comment: You didn't inlcude jQuery and in javascript snipet you can't use <script tag.

Comment: whats the error now?

Comment: code is working as per your need whats the problem,,

Comment: I have two tables in my original code, and the buttons are appended in both the tables. And they are not appended beside the +, but at the end of the table.

Comment: specify the table row or column where you intend to insert the button in your script

Comment: Please see the image link in my post

Comment: SpanB update the html design in your question

Comment: @Cyril : Tried it. It is working here when I run the code snippet...But unfortunately not working when I use it in my code. BTW we are using C# does it make a difference?

Comment: @SpanB Ok edited my answer try now `$(event.srcElement).parent().append(r)`

Comment: @Cyril : It is not working in code snippet too

Comment: @SpanB it must be adding i think may be beacuse of teh styling it may not be visible.

Comment: @Cyril : Thanks it was working. Had to make small modification.

Answer (score 1):

use the following code [view demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLQEEX)

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <p>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</p>

    <button onclick="createbtn()">Create</button>

    <script>
    function createbtn() {
        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
        btn.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLQEEX

Answer (score 0):

Since you saying that you want to display the button beside the + ...add it to the same td.

1) add to the input's td like this  `$(event.srcElement).parent().append(r);`

```js
function test() {
        var r = $('<input/>').attr({
            type: "button",
            id: "field",
            value: 'Project'
        });
    
    $(event.srcElement).parent().append(r);
    }
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
    
    <tr>

        <td style="text-align:center; width:8%"></td>
        <td style="text-align:center; width:8%"><input id="idProject" type="button" style="border:1px solid grey;text-align:center;background-color:#E0EEEE" value="+" onclick=test() /></td>
    </tr>
    
</tbody>
 </table>
  </html>
```